# Using ActiveRecord with key/value pair table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an existing table from a third-party database that I am hooking into that stores key/value pairs. Two columns, one for "param" and the other for "paramvalue". I need to access these stored values for a plugin app that I'm developing, and I'm trying to think of the best way to get the values into the easiest format to use throughout the application. What I had thought of was somehow constructing dynamic methods in the AR model that I could call based on the param name. Something like SysParams.base_url which would map to the record for [base_url,http://www.thesite.com]. Kind of like the built-in AR methods for things like Record.find_by_column_name

The ultimate question: is something like this possible? If so, is it a good idea? If so, how would one go about it?

Comment: does your third party database change or are the key/value pairs constant? If they are constant, how many k/v pairs do you have? dozens? hundreds? thousands?

Comment: Good questions. I don't anticipate the db changing much. There are currently less than 25 entries in that table. The key/values are not set in any manner that is accessible to users, just admins with direct access to the db, so the keys/values should be largely predictable.

Comment: Perhaps a meta-method in the model that I could pass the key name as a param would be a bit easier in my case. Something like, SysParam.getsetting('keyname') that would return the value.

Comment: I tried putting some constant variables in the app controller that just pulled the values from the db by name, but that meant that those values were being set on each action. Not at all ideal. Is there a way I can get those values into the Rails cache and just leave them there until reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how I deal with such stuff, but this is only a good idea if the amount of keys is not too large.

1.Create a model to Access your DB like this one:

app/models/config_table.rb

```
class ConfigTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  # whatever you need here
end
```

2.Create an initializer

config/initializers/admin_config.rb

```
class AdminConfig
  # uncomment this if in development
  #unloadable

  # I assume you have the fields key/value in your 
  # ConfigTable you may need to change this

  def self.all
    # create a cached hash
    @cache ||= ConfigTable.all.inject({}) do |hsh, c_config|
      hsh[c_config.key.to_sym] = c_config.value
      hsh
    end
  end 

  def self.get(key)
    self.all[key.to_sym]
  end

  def self.[](key)
    self.all[key.to_sym]
  end
end
```

Usage examples (anywhere in your Appp):

```
AdminConfig.get(:hostname)
AdminConfig.get('hostname')
AdminConfig[:hostname]
AdminConfig['hostname']
```

If you need to reload your Configuration due to changes, you will have to restart all your running App instances. You may need to adapt the namings of the table/columns of course :)

If you need a solution for bigger sets of key/values, I recommend you to store it in the rail's cache and maybe use redis-store :)

Have fun

Comment: That did it. I figured a hashed value/key set would figure in somehwere, but wasn't sure where to put it or how to read it in exactly. Thanks much!